# Mezclar contenido de archivos en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Mi código es:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync('./archivos/'); //itera todos los archivos 

            for (var a in files) {

                if (fs.statSync('./archivos/'+files[a]).isFile()){
                var nombreFile=files[a];
                console.log(files[a]);
                fs.readFile('./archivos/'+nombreFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                console.log(nombreFile); //solo muentra el ultimo File, como solucionar?, porque solo muestra el ultimo file???
                var contentA=data;
                escritorLector.escribirTraining(nombreFile,contentA);

                for (var b in files) {
                      if(fs.statSync('./archivos/'+files[b]).isFile()){
                        if(nombreFile!=files[b]){
                            fs.readFile('./archivos/'+files[b], 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                                    var contentB=data;
                                    fs.readFile('./archivos/training/'+nombreFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {    
                                    var contentAnterior=data;
                                    var contentAB=contentAnterior+contentB;
                                    console.log(contentAB);
                                        escritorLector.escribirTraining(nombreFile,contentAB);

                                });
                            });
                        }
                     }
                };
                });
            }
    };
```

ese código trabaja en 2 carpetas los cuales son:

```
./archivos/
./archivos/training/
```

La lógica del código de arriba es:

- obtener el contenido de todos los fichero
- crear un archivo nuevo en ./archivos/training/ para cada archivo y
  poner todos los contenidos de todos los archivos
- hacer eso para todos los archivos, es decir crear para cada archivo
  de ./archivos/ su archivo de union en ./archivos/training/

en el codigo comente lo siguiente

> console.log(nombreFile); //solo muentra el ultimo File, como solucionar?, porque solo muestra el ultimo file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer aún estás teniendo problemas con comprender JavaScript y la asincronía. Como ya te he explicado en preguntas anteriores, JavaScript es un lenguaje asíncrono, no funciona igual que en los lenguajes procedurales.

Cuando declaras así:

```
for(var a in files) {
  var file = files[a];
  fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) => {
    console.log(file);
  });
  ...
}
```

> Un closure es un tipo especial de objeto que combina dos cosas: una función, y el entorno en que se creó esa función. El entorno está formado por las variables locales que estaban dentro del alcance en el momento que se creó el closure. - Mozilla docs.

Este `var a` **no pertenece** al `for`, **pertenece a la función**. Grábate esto bien si no siempre te sucederá lo mismo. La referencia de `a` **será recordada en el closure** (callback), mas no **su valor actual**. Este es un error muy reproducido cuando empiezan a trabajar con JS.

***NOTA:*** Puedes leer más sobre closures [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

#### Solución

La solución es tan simple como crear un scope para la variable de control que se ciña al ciclo `for`, y esto lo logras con `let`.

```
for(let a in files) {
  ...
}
```

> Tip: En lugar de obtener el valor actual mediante `files[a]` usa la estructura `for of`: `for(let file of files)`, de ésta manera `file` tiene el valor actual del arreglo.

#### Extra

Tu código puede verse mejor si empezas a *modular*. Recuerda, un código limpio es fácil de escalar y mantener.

```
function processFilesIn(dir) {
  lookup(dir, files => {
    for(let file of files) {
      let fullName = `${dir}/${file}`;
      if(isFile(fullName)) {
        read(fullName, content => {
          console.log(file);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

function lookup(dirName, cb) {
  fs.readdir(dirName, (err, files) => {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    cb(files);
  })
}

function read(name, cb) {
  fs.readFile(name, 'utf8', (err, content) => {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    cb(content);
  });
}

function isFile(path) {
  return fs.statSync(path).isFile();
}
```

Modo de uso:

```
try {
  processFilesIn('directorio');
} catch(e) {
  // maneja el error: e.name, e.message
}
```

Incluso puedes hacer tu código más legible extendiendo a `Error` y creando Errores personalizados.

Comment: ya voy dandome cuenta de muchas cosas, es muy parecido a haskell

Comment: como escribir en un archivo con saltos de linea?

Comment: lo solucione con \r\n

Comment: Así es. Suele bastar solamente con el caracter de nueva línea `\n`. Pero si se encuentra problemas con esto sobre todo en plataformas no Unix, se usa también `\r`.

Comment: como leer linea por linea?

Comment: Para nuevas dudas, publícalas.